# Make a local map based on user's movement in Android

Tags: android, location

I try to make a local map based on movements of user NOT using GPS or Network provider. For example : at first my location is (0,0); when I move to the left 5 meters, so my location is (-5,0). Is it possible to make this type of application in Android?

Comment: How are you going to track the movement if you are not using GPS ?

Comment: you could use the accellerometer for that. e.g. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-accelerometer-on-android--mobile-22125

Comment: @JGPhilip : I try to find another way to do that  without GPS

Comment: @vanao : thank you. I will test it